# How to FullScreen Your Apps With Lion New API

Tags: fullscreen, osx-lion

Lion support full screen app in the separate space. And It's cool to slide the space by gusture.

But I don't know how to make it for my own app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways to get your window to have the fullscreen button in the corner.

```
[[NSApplication sharedApplication] setPresentationOptions:NSFullScreenWindowMask];
```

and

```
[window setCollectionBehavior: NSWindowCollectionBehaviorFullScreenPrimary];
```

I wrote a bit more about it in a blog post [here](http://fredandrandall.com/blog/2011/09/08/how-to-make-your-app-open-in-full-screen-on-lion/)

Answer (score 2):

See [this document](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/FullScreenApp/FullScreenApp.html). Basically, you can call the `toggleFullScreen:` message on a window to put it into fullscreen mode.